# Workflow manager installatin in sharepoint 2016

Tags: 2016, workflow-manger

Hi I created single server sharepoint 2016 farm with SQL SERVER 2016 and OS is windows server 2016. Can we install Workflow manager on that server or it has to be on a separate server\machine?

Are there any issues installing workflow manager on same server as sharepoint 2016 server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly install Workflow Manager CU4 on that server with SQL 2016. There are no specific issues with installing WFM on the same server as SharePoint, it's simply a matter of load that WFM adds (usually minor given usage isn't high).

Comment: please can you share installation steps with best pratcises for installing WFM with CU4

Comment: Info for installing CU4 can be found at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/workflowteam/2017/07/25/wfm-cu4-is-now-available-on-microsoft-download-center/. You can have 1, 3, or 5 WFM servers. No other configuration is valid. Don't forget you need to install the CU4 WFM Client on all of your SharePoint servers. Lastly, always use SSL for WFM.

Comment: hi if i want to install WFM on sharepoint server box also can i install SqlServer 2016 ? or can i use same sql server instance that i was used with sharepoint 2016 farm?

Comment: Please can you share any latest articles that can illustrate with sharepoint 2016